# View is not updating when i make service call in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am making 500 service call in Angular js. each call i need make update the view:

My View is:

```
<div>
       <span>{{countIs}}
</div>
```

MyController is:

```
var myCount =0;

   myArry.forEach(function(item){
      if(item.id){
            myService.serviceCall(function(data){
                    myCount = myCount+1;
                   $scope.countIs = myCount;
               })
    }
})
```

My problem is **"countIs"** variable is not updating the view. Can any one help me.

Thanks Advance.

Comment: can you show us how your controller is linked to the view? how your controller is declared? Are you sure your application is well initiated?

Comment: first you declare to ($scope.countIs= null) in controller before initialize the myCount values.

Comment: @Siva, did any of the answers below address your issue? If so, consider accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your service is not using Angular's built-in `$http` - correct? That is fine - this is how all service not built for Angular work. But this also means that Angular doesn't know when the async operation completes, and so you need to force a digest with `$scope.$apply()`:

```
 myArry.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.id){
       myService.serviceCall(function(data){
          myCount = myCount+1;
          $scope.countIs = myCount;
          $scope.$apply();
       })
    }
 }
```

**Off Topic:** On a side note, making hundreds of HTTP request is a bad design. First of all, this is slow due to network latency (the browser will only allow N consecutive requests to the same origin. On Mobile browsers N = 1, AFAIK). Second, it's unnecessary overloads the server that needs to open and close HTTP connections (and potentially authenticate each request).

Instead, create a single request that asks for all the information at once.

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo below.

My advice is use `angular.forEach` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach()`

and make sure that you declare all your variable before you access them.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

  var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  console.log(myService);

  $scope.countIs = 0;
  var myCount = 0;

  angular.forEach(myArray, function(item) {
    if (item) {
      myService.serviceCall().then(function(data) {
        myCount = myCount + 1;
        $scope.countIs = myCount;
      });
    }



  });
});

app.service('myService', function($http) {


  this.serviceCall = function() {


    return $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json');

  };

  return this;


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    {{countIs}}

  </div>
</div>
```